# Relative Path for background-image in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, background-image

I need to set the relative path for the `AnchorPane` as the project will run on different PCs.

The structure of my project is as follows:

[image: Project structure]

I want to place the photo `logo.png` in the `GUI.fxml` file.

This is the code for the `AnchorPane` contained in the file `GUI.fxml`.

[image: AnchorPane]

I tried with:

```
-fx-background-image: url('../estensione/foto/logo.png');
-fx-background-image: url('../foto/logo.png');
-fx-background-image: url('/foto/logo.png');
```

as well, but I didn't get any results.

I have seen the other questions, but I have not solved the problem.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Where is the CSS file that you're showing the code from?

Comment: See the [Eden tutorial on where to put resources in JavaFX](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/).  It covers locating resources from CSS files.

Comment: @James_D It's not a CSS file, but I have embedded the CSS code in the 'GUI.fxml' file

Comment: @Jewelsea I read your link, but I didn't find any solution. Could you tell me how to proceed?

Comment: Your project structure is a little confusing, as it looks like you have a `resources` directory marked as a "resource root", but that directory appears to be under your source directory? Anyway, given that `resources` is marked as a "resource root", all your non-`*.java` files (such as your PNG files) should be somewhere under it. I suspect with where your PNG files are located currently that they are not being copied to the build output, and therefore cannot be found at run-time.

Comment: Yes, read the Eden tutorial again, refer to the section titled "Loading a resource in CSS", if it is not expanded (arrow pointing up, then click on the arrow to expand the section, so you can read it).  I can't explain resource lookup better than the Eden tutorial, which is excellent.

Comment: Also see the [How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/6395627) Q&A. It provides some good general debugging techniques that can probably be applied to your situation.

Comment: Always use the [Maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for your projects (even if you don't use Maven).  There is simply no need to invent a directory layout. It is easy to get things wrong when the layout is non-standard and more difficult for others to assist you with solutions when something goes wrong (as you are discovering).